# Truncate links/<a> tags in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm utilising Django's [template tag `urlize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize), which automatically converts URLs in a string to a clickable link. E.g:

```
<p>{{ i.comment_text|urlize }}</p>
```

I want to truncate those links. Is this possible using Django syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are taking about `urlizetrunc`

```
<p>{{ i.comment_text|urlizetrunc:10 }}</p>
```

It will truncate your link to certain word length.

However, if you want to change the whole word/ pattern, then no. You cannot do this though django only.

Comment: @Zorgan Is there any further info you want?

Comment: I'd like to remove the https:// & http:// at the start of the links but that will probably require Javascript.

Comment: @Zorgan Yes, django just provide you a short hand. But you have another choice, which is do this in your python backend while not using `urlize`, simply construct the `<a herf=''>{{url_string}}</a>` yourself.